# Digital logic simplification

Tags: digital-logic

For anyone who looked at this post previously, I’ve re-stated the problem below to make it clearer:

I want to create two 8-bit I/O ports, A and B using off-the-shelf 74-series logic, and would appreciate help with a simple design.

Port A is a write-only control port, one bit b3 sets Output mode where port B acts as an output (mainly). Another bit b4 sets Input mode where port B is just an input. The two modes are mutually exclusive.

**Output mode**

A write to Port B should latch 8 bits of input data at its output.
A read of Port B should return the value of a separate input line (B) connected to b2.
Apart from these requirements and the mode set bits in Port A, no other bits matter

**Input mode**

A read from Port B should return the state of two inputs R1 (b1) and R0 (b0). Other inputs don’t matter.
A write to Port A should latch W1 (b1) and W0 (b0) at the output. Any writes to Port A will always set the I and O bits correctly for the selected mode.
Apart from these requirements and the mode set bits in Port A, no other bits matter

**Port Diagram**

I’ve sketched out the ports. I sets Input mode, O sets Output mode. I can create a Select line for each port and Read and Write lines.
Can anyone suggest a minimal design for ports A & B using 74-series logic please? I'll use DIP parts to prototype a solution, so the smallest number of packages possible helps. I could do this with a RS FF, two octal latches and one octal buffer.

But given some of the bit redundancy/don't care, is there a simpler solution? That is the key question.

No PLDs or other exotic solutions pls :-)

I'm sure many people reading this will want to help me by enabling me to learn more so as to figure this out for myself. But I just don't have the time or mental capacity to do so. So I'd really appreciate responses from logic design engineers who look at the requirement and say "this is so simple" and who can propose a basic design, rather than helpful suggestions about what to read.

Thanks,

David00

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you sure that the I/O ports in question were not implemented using a standard part?  Certainly by the 8086-era designers were not building ports from discrete logic.  It was much more cost effective to use an I/O port device.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - Hi, Just FYI the OP [already asked on Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/653776). I think it's fair to say they were not happy with the responses there. They were recommended to ask on Retrocomputing.SE, so they reposted the question here and when I saw that, I closed the one on EE to avoid cross-site duplication of effort. That's where we are at the moment :(

Comment: If the two mode control bits allow X1 *and* 1X, 11 means *both modes simultaneously* and there is no need to store them. Otherwise, one needs to take priority: 01&1X for Transfer mode or X1&10 for Output mode. A single RS-FF may be enough.

Comment: Points not speaking *standard I/O component*: 1) lack of protocol 2) BSY at bit2 not coming from the pin bit2 goes to on output.

Comment: if you say timing's not an issue, wouldn't then using a cabable microcontroller like e.g. the 2040 on a pi pico be a way simpler solution than using TTL chips? simply connect all your 12 used pins to gpio pins and solve the rest with software

Comment: [(C)PLD would be great if that gets me down to *one* device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/653776/port-circuit-replacement?noredirect=1#comment1737923_653776) There are 6 input pins (bus3…7+BSY), 6+2 output (P2…P9) and 5 bidirectional (bus012+P01), +at least 2 for port selection - too much for a 22V10, even for a 26V12 *if* W0W1/P8P9 need to be latched: no single *skinny* DIP I'd know of.

Comment: (Consider tagging [tag:repair]. And incorporating information from comments to the EE question.)

Comment: @jwh20 - This was originally done in 74-series logic, and with just a few parts, as a cheap and simple design

Comment: @greybeard - more good questions. The two modes are mutually exclusive. As for CPLD, I suspected not enough pins and don’t want a bigger device that may need a tiny package like QFP. Partly as hard to solder, and also as I can’t inspect  intermediate nodes and check against what I think firmware is doing.

Comment: @Tommylee2k - your suggestion falls into the realm of an exotic solution :-) I’m sure it’s viable, but isn’t the desired end state - which is to create a simple 74-series design.

Comment: `The module the ports were on hasn't survived` Any chance to get a picture, or *missing declared dead*? Consider revealing more about make, type, model, revision.

Comment: @greybeard - I am disassembling some ROM code to reverse-engineer the functionality. Nothing else exists. I’d prefer not to explain more, as that opens up other lines of enquiry and seems to create confusion. Assume no existing system pls.

Comment: Something has gone wrong. There's no longer any text relating to an actual question.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your post like that.  That makes it hard for readers to understand any of the answers.

Comment: @TobySpeight - Please don't edit my original post. As noted, I needed to simplify it which I have now done.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand how Stack Exchange works.  Questions and answers are maintained _collaboratively_ by members - excluding an individual from the process is not possible or desirable.

Comment: @TobySpeight - I'm not seeking to exclude anyone. But I had noted in the updated post that I was redrafting the problem statement, which I have now done. Resurrecting the old post doesn't help.

Comment: This question seems to have very little to do with retrocomputing. It probably should have stayed on Electronics.

Comment: @user3840170 - Yes, I realised that and was in the process of removing the post and planning a simplified post back on Electronics, but then my post here was re-instated by TobySpeight and Antonio51 provided a good solution. The only reason I posted in Retrocomputing was a user of Electronics recommended I do so.

Comment: @SamGibson Not really great, as this is in not really RC specific, but a generic question about TTL logic. It will get a similar treatment here as on EE, if not harder. You may not like it, but it's EE at it's core - and best :))

Comment: @Raffzahn - I agree with you! I did not migrate the question to here, and I can't prevent an OP from asking a question on any SE site which they want to. || I'm sure that the EE user who suggested asking it here did so in good faith, even if they were misguided. || From the OP's last edit to the EE question (which removed all details making it a non-question, so I have deleted it there) it's clear that they have "moved" the question to here (their words), so it is out of *my* hands, sorry. (IMHO the question has been significantly clarified over here, compared to the initial version at EE.)

Comment: @SamGibson - Please feel free to move this post back to EE. I removed all the details from the original EE version as I was in the process of simplifying the question to provide more clarity - and I stated that. You decided to delete the question on EE before I was able to update it with the simplified version, so I then simplified it on RC. In hindsight you could have let me move it back to EE. I would then have asked for help in closing down the RC version.

Comment: @David00 - "*Please feel free to move this post back to EE.*" Not possible, once it's off EE I cannot move it. Also, as you now have answers here, it is not eligible for *migration* back again. "*You decided to delete the question on EE before I was able to update it with the simplified version*" Yes, your edit of the question on EE was unfortunately premature, since that caused it to be a "non-question" which was flagged to us. You also made it very clear that you were unhappy with the way things went on EE. I don't want you to be unhappy! Not to worry, you have answers here now. Good luck!

Comment: This history of this question just feels bad.  The OP didn't do anything in bad faith, but the question was still impaled on all of the rules, both written and unwritten.  Perhaps if the OP had hired counsel instead of being pro se then this question would still have a home.

Comment: @Raffzahn - you are one of the people who have flagged my question as needing details or clarity. Can you explain what kind of detail or clarity you are expecting to see please?

Comment: @David00 No, I flagged it as not fitting - the system only displays the majority reason. The reason why I flagged it that way is that it's a basic question about TTL logic. Neither about computing or history. Thus EE would be the right place to ask. It would need a lot more focus on a specific classic system which did not use a 8255 or alike and need a very specific replacement. Cant see that here. All it asks for is 'build me a TTL circuit that can be used as port'

Comment: @Raffzah - I agree that it’s not fitting.  I initially posted in Electronics as I was asking for a logic design. But EE users were distracted by the computer association that I shared to give context. An EE user recommended I post in RC. But even then only a few people seemed able to read the question properly. So I decided to simplify it to focus just on the basic logic requirement and move it back to EE. But my original post on EE was deleted - not by me. I’ve since been told it cannot be moved back. I have tried to do my best - but the outcome from a forum experience has been disappointing.

Comment: @Leo B. - can you please explain why you think my post lacks clarity or detail?

Comment: @user3840170 - can you please explain why you think my post lacks clarity or detail?

Comment: @another-dave - can you please explain why you think my post lacks clarity or detail?

Comment: @Retrograde - can you please explain why you think my post lacks clarity or detail?

Comment: @SamGibson Actually, this was reposted, not migrated.

Comment: @user3840170 - Yes agreed, I said the same thing in [this earlier comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26435/digital-logic-simplification?noredirect=1#comment91233_26435). That was my point - the reposting bypassed any of the checks & balances which would have been involved in a *migration* request (either multiple user votes or mod involvement). I'm genuinely pleased that the OP got answers. Given the repeated expressions of disappointment they made on EE, I'm surprised that there was any plan to move the question back to EE after it had been answered here! *shrug*

Comment: @SamGibson But that means this post isn't blocked from being migrated, contrary to what you said.

Comment: @user3840170 - "*this post isn't blocked from being migrated, contrary to what you said*" Please re-read what I said. I didn't say it was *blocked* from being migrated, I said it was not *eligible* as it now has answers. See the FAQ article with the flowchart for migration [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249) (top flowchart, orange box). Also, as I said before, migration to EE makes no sense as the OP said several times in the (now deleted) EE question how badly things went there. I don't want the OP to be unhappy again! Please take this to Meta if you want to discuss further.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon what you're driving, the simplest approach may be to have a port which is always in "output mode", but with resistors driving its outputs.  In that scenario, you could simply use a 73HC374 or 74HC377 chips to drive the outputs, and some kind of three-state driver, possibly with latch, to drive the inputs.

If you're willing to change your addressing scheme slightly, the design could be done fairly elegantly with three chips: two 6-bit registers, at least one of which has output enable, and some kind of device with a 3-state output that feeds the bus.  The two registers, together, would latch the state of the data bus along with an address bit.  The register that latches the address would always have its output enabled, and the output associated with the address would control the output enable for the other register.

Writing to one I/O address would place the device into input mode and set the states of the unidirectional I/O pins.  Writing to the other address would set the device to output mode and set the state of all I/O pins.

If you happen to be using a 6502, I'd suggest using something like a 74HC4053 to drive D5-D7 so that you can use a couple of address bits to select one of four I/O arrangements (calling your inputs A, B, C)

```
A1 A0 | D7 D6 D5
0  0  | A  B  C
0  1  | C  B  C
1  0  | A  C  B
1  1  | B  C  B
```

This would allow code to read the state of all three bits at once, but would also allow the BIT instruction to test for any bit on the N flag, and any pair of bits on the N and V flags together.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the principle of what you are saying, but I can’t visualise the detail. Plus I have some constraints re bit positions - and have more bits to worry about in Port A that I haven’t show for simplicity. 

However, in Antonio51’s diagram the two control signals, “Output & “Input” at Port A are latched and mutually exclusive. You’ve made me realise that I don’t need an RS-FF, I can use those to directly enable/disable Port B output and input functionality.

Comment: If you have time to sketch your design, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @David00: For the input functions, the 4053 is a triple two-input multiplexer.  D5 is chosen from either C or B based upon whether A1 is low or high.  D6 likewises chooses between them, but with the roles reversed.  D7 is connected to either A or to D5 based upon A0.

Answer (score 0):

Not the real behavior but ... on the way.
Some things to be "corrected".

[image]

Comment: Thank you for drafting this! It's roughly how I envisaged a solution. But given the bit redundancy (many bits don't matter), do you see any scope for optimisation?

Comment: X8 could be replaced by SN7475 (4 latches, not TS). Also X10 is not needed. Just bypass O0..O2 to D0..D2, but InpOP should be RD strobed signal. Address decoder common for all addresses used except A0.

Comment: @David00 Optimising circuits made out of logic chips like this is different to optimising logic in general: you're optimising the number of chips (and/or their cost) rather than the number of gates. TTL designs can sometimes feel wasteful in their use of gates because that's just how it turned out to be cheapest or easiest to build. (And you want easy-to-build since you forbade "exotic solutions".) Additionally, further optimisations will depend on what's upstream of this circuit, but you are remaining tight-lipped about what that is.

Comment: @Antonio51 - Thank you Antonio

Comment: @pndc - Yes, I do understand the tradeoff, and why today someone would just treat this a problem that can be answered by VHDL/Verilog and some kind of PLD. But where's the fun there? :-) As for upstream, I've avoided touching on this as It's not clear, and not something I can answer right now. When I ventured into this before, it just opened up a can of worms. Antonio51 has provided a good solution.

Comment: @Antonio51 - No, I do not. Just a ROM image. But thank you once again for your diagram, it was very helpful. For someone who says their English isn't that good, you answered the question better than anyone else! :-)

Comment: No worries. Google translate, "grammarly" on, some "corrections" and a little "guess" ... :-)